# Device Owner не работает в Android TV Box

Tags: java, android, adb

Я хочу установить мое приложение в качестве владельца устройства на Android TV Box, и я получаю следующее исключение.

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner 
    "com.android.testapp/.receivers.AdminReceiver"
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set package com.android.testapp as 
    device owner.
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:115)
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:82)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:38)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:251)`

Аккаунтов на девайсе нет. Это работает на телефонах, но на Android TV Box это не работает.

Comment: Версия Андроида какая - и что за модель девайса

Comment: @Barmaley Mi Box 3, Android 6.0.1

Comment: Xiaomi известен своими косяками со своей оболочкой MIUI. Попробуйте вырубить оптимизацию MIUI если не поможет - тогда получайте рут

Comment: @Barmaley я так понимаю, в  боксах оптимизацию нельзя отключить, только в телефоне?!

Comment: без понятия... оптимизация MIUI вырубается в настройках разработчика, а она обычно скрыта и раскрывается специальным образом (думаю одинаково для все Xiaomi) - вкурите гугль

Comment: [Например](https://www.google.ru/search?q=xiaomi+developer+mode)